# Spring boot JPA - Why is no data inserted in the intermediate table using using embeddable?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am doing a API Rest with Spring Boot and MySQL and I have the next relation:
[image]

To do this, the first thing I do is create a type @Embeddable.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class UserInterestKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "interest_id",nullable = false)
    private long interestId;

    @Column(name = "user_id",nullable = false)
    private long userId;

    public UserInterestKey() {
    }

    public UserInterestKey(long interestId, long userId) {
        this.interestId = interestId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    //get and set for interestId and userId

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserInterestKey that = (UserInterestKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(interestId, that.interestId) &&
                Objects.equals(userId, that.userId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(interestId, userId);
    }
}
```

Then, I create the entity that uses the EmbeddedId type:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "rel_user_interest")
public class RelUserInterest {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserInterestKey id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("interestId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "interest_id", nullable = false)
    Interest interest;

    int priority;

    public RelUserInterest() {
    }
    //get and set for id, user, interest and priority
```

This is the User entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column (unique = true) private String email;

    @NotNull private int age;
    @NotNull private String genre;

    @NotNull private String userName;

    @NotNull private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @NotNull
    Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();

    public User (){
    }

    public User(@NotNull String email, @NotNull int age, @NotNull String genre, @NotNull String userName, @NotNull String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // set and get for id, email, age, genre, username, password and priority.
}
```

This is the interest entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Interest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @NotNull private String nameInterest;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "interest")
    @NotNull
    Set<RelUserInterest> priority = new HashSet<>();

    public Interest() {
    }

    public Interest(String nameInterest) {
        this.nameInterest = nameInterest;
    }
    // get and set for id, nameInterest and priority
}
```

This is the part of the controller

```
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@Validated @RequestBody NewUserDTO userDTO, BindingResult result) {
        //more code
        User user = new User(userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getAge(), userDTO.getGenre(), userDTO.getUserName(),userDTO.getPassword());
        Set<InterestDTO> interestStr = userDTO.getInterest();
        RelUserInterest rel;
        for(InterestDTO interest: interestStr){
            rel = new RelUserInterest();
            rel.setPriority(interest.getPriority());
            Interest i = interestService.getInterestByName(interest.getNameInterest());
            rel.setInterest(i);
            rel.setUser(user);
            user.getPriority().add(rel);
            i.getPriority().add(rel);
        }
        usersService.addUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Usuario añadido"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**PROBLEM:** The database is well created as you can see in the first image. The problem is that the intermediate table (**rel_user_interest**) is empty, nothing is inserted. Does anyone find any problem in the code and can help me please?
[image]

**UPDATE 17/11/2020**

This is a JSON example that I want to send

```
{
    "email": "sd@email.com",
    "userName": "sd",
    "password": "1234",
    "passwordConfirm": "1234",
    "age": 21,
    "genre": "Women",
    "roles": [
        "user"
    ],
    "interest": [
        {
            "nameInterest": "Museum",
            "priority": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I followed this tutorial [Many-to-Many Using a Composite Key](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)

- Spring Boot version: 2.3.5.RELEASE
- Java version: 1.8

Comment: I think you need some `cascade` attributes on your `@OneToMany` annotations.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh no, this doesn't work. I have add cascade = CascadeType.MERGE to `@OneToMany` annotations and doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: what about `CascadeType.ALL`, and I think it's better to have Cascade on one side of your `@OneToMany`s.